# Solving the hassle of starting Apache Tomcat from command line by navigating to bin directory

Tags: java, servlets, environment-variables, tomcat7

I am currently self-studying servlets. It has been cakewalk so far.

I compile my Java programs from command line and I have set the `classpath` environment variable to `D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\lib\servlet-api.jar`
so that I do not have to keep entering it over and over again.

However,
my *development environment* and *deployment environment* are in different locations (duh). Every time I have to start Tomcat I have to navigate to the `bin` folder and then call `STARTUP.BAT`

This is quite annoying.
My question is:
**Is there a way so that I can start Tomcat right from the directory where my Java sources are stored ?** and avoid the hassle of navigating all the time ?
Something akin to:
`E:\Servlet Projects\Project-1\src > startup.BAT` and Tomcat would start

**Misc:**

Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the path to Tomcat's bin folder to `path` environment variable. If a batch/command file is not found in the current folder, then the operating system will look for the file in all paths definied in the `path` environment variable, in the same order as they're been definied.

Note that this all has completely nothing to do with Java, Servlets, nor Tomcat.